# Server handler event info parameters google apps script

Tags: events, google-apps-script

A simple app:

```
function doGet() {
  return(test());
}

function test(){
  var smiley = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("TT Bomgar Feedback");
  var textIn = smiley.createTextBox().setName("text");
  var textOut = smiley.createLabel().setId("label").setVisible(false);
  var button = smiley.createSubmitButton("Submit");
  var handler = smiley.createServerHandler("handler");
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  smiley.add(button);
  smiley.add(textIn);
  smiley.add(textOut);
  return(smiley);
}

function handler(e){
  app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var text = e.parameter.text;
  app.getElementById("label").setVisible(true).setText(text);
  return(app);
}
```

In the handler function, `var text` is always `undefined`. This means that the following is returned:

[image]

So, undefined is printed instead of "some text".

I don't understand why though, because I have correctly set the name of the text box element in the test function ...

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a callBackElemnt to the handler so that its value will get passed to the handler function. In normal practice, we just add the top most element containing all other elements. But you can also add all the elements whose value you want to pass.

modified script

```
var handler = smiley.createServerHandler("handler");
handler.addCallbackElement(textIn);
button.addClickHandler(handler);
```

Comment: Thanks. The value that is being sent to the server and printed to the screen is now Generic. Any thoughts on what would be causing this, and how I can avoid this issue ? thanks

Comment: try to print Utilities.jsonStringify(e.parameter) and check if you are getting the required params or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add callback element to your server handler:

```
...
var handler = smiley.createServerHandler("handler");
handler.addCallbackElement(textIn);
button.addClickHandler(handler);
...
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_serverhandler#addCallbackElement